# startReactApplication fails when called from AsyncTask - React Native in Android

Tags: android, react-native

Starting from the cryptic error: `java.lang.AssertionError: Attached DialogModule to host with pending alert but no FragmentManager (not attached to an Activity).`

I have this in `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myManager = new MyManager(this);
    myManager.start();
}

public void onManagerReady() {
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
        .setApplication(getApplication())
        .setJSBundleFile("assets://index.js")
        .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
        .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
        .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyReactCode");
    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}
...
```

Calling `onManagerReady` from `onCreate` works as expected. But when I use an `AsyncTask` inside the manager, it fails:

```
public interface ManagerHandler { void onJobReady(); }
```

...

```
public class Manager implements ManagerHandler {
    public MyManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void start() {
        new AsyncJob(context, this).execute("");
    }

    @Override
    public void onJobReady() {
      ((MainActivity)context).onManagerReady();
    }

    private class AsyncJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final ManagerHandler handler;

      public AsyncJob(Context context, ManagerHandler handler) {
          this.context = context;
          this.handler = handler;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        handler.onJobReady();
      }
    ...
    }
```

I omitted some AsyncTask boilerplate - let me assure you that the AsyncTask is working and that onManagerReady() is getting called at the proper time.
I also tried messing with threads and "run on ui thread", no luck. It's interesting to note that even using `Thread.sleep()` messes React, even without AsyncTask or calls from/to other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's probably too late to help you, but maybe someone else will find this answer useful.

Basically your `MainActivity` is a subclass of `ReactActivity`. You need to replace it with your own class similar to `ReactActivity` (just copy-paste). Change name of method `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` to something else, and call this method when rest of your app is ready for react. 
Also you need to change `onResume()`, to change state only when react is loaded:

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
      mLifecycleState = LifecycleState.RESUMED;
      mReactInstanceManager.onResume(this, this);
    }
  }
```

Call onResume at the end of method where you initialize react.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the solution I found was very close to yours - starting a new Activity that subclasses ReactActivity after completing the callbacks from the manager to the MainActivity.